# Uncaught TypeError: THREE.GLTFLoader is not a constructor ("there are questions exactly like this one but the answers didn't work for me")

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js, gltf

note: I have a renderer, scene, camera but I didn't include the code because I think it's unnecessary but if you have to look at it I will edit the post

```
  import * as THREE from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/build/three.module.js";
    import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

      let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('assets/trash/scene.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
      scene.add(gltf.scene);
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried `new GLTFLoader()` instead of `new THREE.GLTFLoader()`?

Comment: This question has the exact same situation as yours: [threejs gltf loader not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70244038/threejs-gltf-loader-not-a-constructor)